# Why is it deleting from other variable while I am Removing from different variable in C#.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq

I have the below code.
I am removing the data in **RecoveryRecords** variable based on the below conditions if it is not in the ValidClaimControl Numbers.

After executing the line at **RecoveryRecords.Remove(s)**, it is removing from **records** variable also. I actually need the data from **records** variable.

I am wondering how i can retain data in **records** variable?

```
List<List<Field>> records = new List<List<Field>>();
List<List<Field>> RecoveryRecords = new List<List<Field>>();

//Some Logic here to populate records variable

RecoveryRecords = records;
List<string> validClaimControlNo = new List<string>();

//Some Logic here to populate validClaimControlNo variable

foreach (List<Field> s in RecoveryRecords.ToList())
{
    foreach (Field f in s)
    {
        if (!(validClaimControlNo.Contains(f.Value)))
          RecoveryRecords.Remove(s);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By enumerating the elements into a new List

```
RecoveryRecords = records.ToList();
```

(much like you do in the foreach loop by saying `RecoveryRecords.ToList()`)

Answer (score 6):

This line doesn't do what you think, I suspect:

```
RecoveryRecords = records;
```

It's just copying the value of `records`, which is a *reference* to an object, as the new value of `RecoveryRecords`. The two variables refer to the same object. If you wanted a *new list* containing a copy of the data from `records`, you need to do that explicitly, e.g.

```
RecoveryRecords = new List<List<Field>>(records);
```

or

```
RecoveryRecords = records.ToList();
```

Note that even this would only be a shallow copy of the list - if you wrote:

```
RecoveryRecords[0].Add(new Field());
```

that change would be visible in `records[0]` as well, as they'd both be references to the same `List<Field>`.

Answer (score 2):

Replace these two lines:

```
List<List<Field>> records = new List<List<Field>>();
List<List<Field>> RecoveryRecords = new List<List<Field>>(records);
```

and Remove this line:

```
RecoveryRecords = records;
```

Comment: Thank GOD i have made a mark, otherwise i was thinking if i was wrong :P :)

Answer (score 1):

This is why:

```
RecoveryRecords = records;
```

You don't have two variables pointing to separate lists, you have two variables pointing to the same list.

Make a copy of the list:

```
RecoveryRecords = new List<List<Field>>(records);
```

Note: Now you have two separate lists, but you should be aware that the `List<Field>` items in the lists are the same in both lists.

Answer (score 1):

Using this line:

```
RecoveryRecords = records;
```

you are passing the pointer of `records` to `RecoveryRecords` (*reference*), this mean that every change in the `records` list is effective on `RecoveryRecords`. So you should clone the list and you can do this using this code:

```
RecoveryRecords = new List<List<Field>>(records);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are shallow copying your records object with this line of code

```
RecoveryRecords = records;
```

You need to do a deep copy

```
RecoveryRecords = new List<List<Field>>(records);
```

This is a common theme across many programming languages.  Wikipedia explains it fairly well, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_copy.